# Repeating While Statement

Tags: sql, while-loop

I need help on a While Statement, I have never used one before and was wondering had to repaeat the sequence until I hit a target:

For Example

```
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
Until 5000
```

I have tried to write my own but have become stuck:

```
USE Occupancy
CREATE TABLE Bookings2
(Booking_Skey   INT IDENTITY (1,1) not null,
PitchType_Skey  INT  not null)

DECLARE @PitchType_Skey INT
SET @PitchType_Skey = 1
WHILE (@PitchType_Skey <= 4)

BEGIN
INSERT INTO Bookings2(PitchType_Skey)
SELECT @PitchType_Skey
SET @PitchType_Skey = @PitchType_Skey + 1
END
```

Comment: Hi, your question doesn't give to much to help you, can you tell us what do you want in the While.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish here.  For example, are you trying to repeat the sequence "1,2,3,4" 5000 times?  For that matter, I'm not quite sure what your tables are intended for.  Essentially, I could tell you how to use a WHILE loop, but what problem are you using the WHILE loop and the Bookings2 table to solve exactly?

Comment: Your code runs fine.  What is the problem?

Comment: Works for me Sql Server 2012. What are you getting?

Comment: Its to populate dummy data (I'm new to SQL) I need the code to populate 5000 rows of data repeating the sequence 1,2,3,4. So 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4 I will also need do another column later that does the same thing but it will 1 to 126 repeating until 5000. I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks for the followup, @wafw1971.  The request definitely makes sense now.  Might not hurt to include that explanation in the question text itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your select within the while with

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN @PitchType_Skey % 4 = 0 THEN 4 ELSE @PitchType_Skey % 4 END)
```

% is Modulus or Remainder, so it gets the remainder of @PitchType_Skey / 4 (guaranteeing a value less than 4)

Then you have to replace 0 with 4

```
WHILE (@PitchType_Skey <= 5000)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Bookings2(PitchType_Skey)
  SELECT (CASE WHEN @PitchType_Skey % 4 = 0 THEN 4 ELSE @PitchType_Skey % 4 END)
  SET @PitchType_Skey = @PitchType_Skey + 1
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You Actually don't need a while since you can just use master..spt_values

```
WITH t1250
     AS (SELECT TOP 1250 Row_number() 
                           OVER( 
                             ORDER BY t1.number) AS N 
         FROM   master..spt_values t1 
                CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2) 
INSERT INTO Bookings2
      (PitchType_Skey)
    
SELECT v.number 
FROM   master..spt_values v 
       CROSS JOIN t1250
WHERE  v.type = 'P' 
       AND v.number > 0 
       AND v.number < 5
```

[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/96485/demo-for-14776407)

Or using Moduls as [msmucker0527 did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14776567/119477) it

```
WITH t5000
     AS (SELECT TOP 5000 Row_number() 
                           OVER( 
                             ORDER BY t1.number) AS N 
         FROM   master..spt_values t1 
                CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2) 
INSERT INTO Bookings2
   (PitchType_Skey)
SELECT 
      CASE WHEN n % 4 = 0 THEN 4 ELSE n % 4 END
FROM t5000
```

[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/96486/demo-2-for-14776407)